# Add remote image as texture during loop

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am very new to Unity3d.
I have a JSON array that contains the parameters of the prefabs I want to create at runtime.

I want to display images that are stored on my server in the scene.
I have a prefab "iAsset" that has a plane (mesh filter) and I want to load the image files as the texture of the plane.

I am able to Instatiate the prefabs however the prefab is showing up as a white square. This is my code:

```
    for(var i = 0; i < bookData.Assets.Count; i++){
    GameObject newAsset = null;

    newAsset = (GameObject)Instantiate(iasset, new Vector3(2*i, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);

    if(!imageAssetRequested )            
    {
        remoteImageAsset = new WWW(((BookAssets)bookData.Assets[i]).AssetContent);

        imageAssetRequested = true;
    }

    if(remoteImageAsset.progress >=1)
    {
        if(remoteImageAsset.error == null)
        {
            loadingRemoteAsset = false;
            newAsset.renderer.material.mainTexture = remoteImageAsset.texture;
        }
    }

}
```

the urls to the images on my server is retrieved from the JSON array:

```
((BookAssets)bookData.Assets[i]).AssetContent);
```

The code builds without any errors, I would very much appreciate any help to display the remote images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not waiting for your downloads to complete.

The WWW class is asynchronous, and will commence the download. However, you need to either poll it (using the code you do have above) at a later time, or use a yield WWW in a CoRoutine that will block your execution (within that CoRoutine) until the download finishes (either successfully or due to failure).

Refer to [Unity Documentation for WWW](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/WWW.html)

Note however, that page sample code is wrong, and Start is not a CoRoutine / IEnumarator. Your code would look something like :

```
void Start()
{
  ... your code above ...
  StartCoroutine(DownloadImage(bookData.Assets[i]).AssetContent, newAsset.renderer.material.mainTexture));
}


IEnumerator DownloadImage(string url, Texture tex) 
{
  WWW www = new WWW(url);
  yield return www;
  tex.LoadImage(www.bytes)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I had to make a few changes to get it to work. Instead of passing the texture to the DownloadImage, I passed the gameObject and then changed it's texture once it had finished downloading using: tex.renderer.material.mainTexture = www.texture;

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, I meant to type `tex.LoadImage(www.bytes)`. But passing the GameObject works well too!